# Webpart interaction

Tags: web-part

Although I've been doing a lot of sharepoint 2010 branding lately, programming webparts is something completely new for me.

1. I need to put together three webparts.
2. I want to create a Webpart1 (Dropdownlist), Webpart2 (Checkbox) and Webpart3 (GridView)
3. My grid in webpart3 should display data based on filter values from the other two webparts.

Do I have to implement connectable webparts to do this?

Ie:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/4035/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584164(office.11).aspx

Many thanks,

KS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should make the Web Parts connectable - if you really want them as three Web Parts.

Why can't you make one Web Part containing all three controls?

Comment: Because I guess my boss wants each one of them to be re-usable.thx.

Comment: to increase reusability you could go for user controls and a virtual web part.

Comment: Do you mean that I can just create a standard asp.net usercontrol and deploy that to a sharepoint site? Thx.

Comment: You would deploy the user control to %SharePointRoot%/CONTROLTEMPLATES and then reuse it whether you want it on your masterpage or loaded from WebPart code using LoadControl("path/name.ascx").

Comment: What project template should I choose in VS if I wanted to create a re-usable webpart that can be used in Sharepoint and in a Asp.Net website? Hmmm, just a UserControl? Thx.